# How to get a specific field from a text file using python

Tags: python, file

I have a text file named `login.txt` has the following data:

```
{'Username':'hazem', 'Password':'000'}
{'Username':'john', 'Password':'123'}
```

And I have a function has two parameters `Username` and `Password`

Once I pass the parameters as example `john` and `123`

I want to check if the username and password is right or not from the text file.

But I don't know exactly how to read the key value pairs data from a text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the file line-by-line and call `json.loads(line)`, which will return a dictionary, and then you can check the `"Username"` and `"Password"` keys.

Comment: And how exactly can I check for a specific `"Username"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of iterating over the files + ast.literal_eval.

For example:

```
import ast

file_location = 'SomeFileLocation\text_file.txt'
# Open File and iterate over lines
with open(file_location, 'r+') as f:
    for single_line in f:
        dict_to_check = ast.literal_eval(single_line)
        user_name = dict_to_check['Username']
        password = dict_to_check['Password']
```

Comment: I guess it works but how can I check if the parameter I've passed is same as the username or password in a specific column?

Comment: I edited my original answer. Just grab the values in the dictionary, and then check them against whatever logic you'd like.

Comment: Yes thanks bro, can you please tell me the last thing which is getting a specific column

Answer (score 1):

Save the credentials to JSON file and you can access them with JSON libary

login.json

```
[
  {
    "username": "john",
    "password": "1234"
  },
  {
    "username": "johny",
    "password": "12sdfds34"
  }
]
```

```
import json
with open('login.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
    for i in d:
        print(i["username"], i["password"])
```